# Ironing out Time zones between input and saved database data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

So an input form provides from a datetime_select

```
"meeting"=>{"start_time[...] "start_time(4i)"=>"13", "start_time(5i)"=>"15"}
```

The controller then takes this time to calculate an end_time based on a parent's attribute

```
@initiate = DateTime.civil(date["start_time(1i)"].to_i, date["start_time(2i)"].to_i, date["start_time(3i)"].to_i, date["start_time(4i)"].to_i, date["start_time(5i)"].to_i)
params[:meeting][:end_time] = @initiate + (@product.minutes.to_i).minutes
```

however, given a duration of 60 minutes (being 1 hour off GMT makes things more interesting!), the database is being populated with the following:

```
["start_time", "2017-12-29 13:15:00.000000"], ["end_time", "2017-12-29 15:15:00.000000"]
```

What is the most effective, yet concise, manner to resolve this?

*Note* this is so that the database is written with coherent timezone data, this excludes user time_zone viewing issues...

Comment: There is a parameter on `civil` to include an offset, but it defaults to UTC (0) when not specified.  Therefore your start time is in UTC, and your end time is also in UTC, so nothing here is affected by your local time zone and thus the only way you'd see 15:15 as the end time is if you actually added 120 minutes not 60.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.  the input data is in UTC. But by running the calculation on a datetime format, rails (or ruby) is converting the calculation into local time zone, before translating that into UTC. Thus the extra 60 minutes.  Now assuming users are in different timezones and want to look at the data in their native zone, this handling in the middle has to be agnostic.  Haven't figured a non-blunt way to do so...

Comment: Interesting.  If you set `config.time_zone = 'UTC'`, does that help?  (in `config/application.rb` file)

Comment: Interesting thought, yes it does solve the calculation issue.  But that becomse un-rails-ish, yes?

Comment: Not sure.  I don't do much with Rails.  But in general, depending on a server's time zone setting is not a great idea.  Setting it in the environment is a little better, but ideally Rails would use the offset provided in the `DateTime` when you did the addition rather than using the global setting.  I don't see that documented anywhere, so perhaps it's a bug?  IDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that performing addition or subtraction on a `DateTime` does an implicit time zone conversion using the global `config.time_zone` setting, rather than the offset provided in the `DateTime` (which defaults to 0 when not specified).

To work around this, set `config.time_zone = 'UTC'` in the `config/application.rb` file.

This will affect the entire application, using UTC instead of the system default time zone.